# How exactly to use @font-face rule?

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

I'm currently running into an issue where I'm trying to change to the font on my website to `Helvetica Neue Bold`. I've done some research on this and maybe I'm just missing the the mark here. I've taken the fonts and ran them through the font face generator, second I created a folder in the css folder labeled "Fonts" with those designated font within the folder. Third I added the following code into `theme.css`

```
@font-face {
font-family: "Helvetica Neue Bold";
src: url("css/fonts/HelveticaNeueLTStd-Bd.eot");
src: 
url("css/fonts/HelveticaNeueLTStd-Bd.woff") format("woff"),
url("css/fonts/HelveticaNeueLTStd-Bd.ttf") format("truetype"),

}
```

Lastly, In my preview mode using Brackets Coding Program I'm using the code

```
     <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
<font face="Helvetica Neue Bold" color="white" size="4">REVOL</font>
    </a>
```

and I am not seeing the font change to desired font face? I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. Any ideas? Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> The `<font>` tag was used in HTML 4 to specify the font face, font size, and color of text. For more info about it please refer [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_font.asp)

So the way you can apply the font is directly you can use `font-family` in css(inline or external) with the name provided as part of `@font-face`.

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue Bold";
  src: url("css/fonts/HelveticaNeueLTStd-Bd.eot");
  src: url("css/fonts/HelveticaNeueLTStd-Bd.woff") format("woff"), url("css/fonts/HelveticaNeueLTStd-Bd.ttf") format("truetype"),
}

.paragraph {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue Bold";
}
```

```html
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
  <p class="paragraph">REVOL</p>
</a>

<!-- or -->
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
  <p style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue Bold'">REVOL</p>
</a>
```